# Fiber product an difference of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $j:W\to X$ be a closed immersion of a schemes and $f:Y\to X$ a morphism. The basechange of $j$ along $f$ defines a closed immersion $W\times_X Y\to Y$.

The inclusion $k:X\setminus W\to X$ and the inclusion $l:Y\setminus (W\times_X Y)\to Y$ are both open immersions.

Is the fiber product
$$
(X\setminus W)\times_X Y
$$
isomorphic to $Y\setminus(W\times_X Y)$ in the canonical way, i.e. is $l$ the basechange of $k$ along $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=X\setminus W$. The natural morphism $f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times_XY$ is an isomorphism. The closed immersion $W\times_XY\rightarrow Y$ induces a homeomorphism onto $f^{-1}(W)$. So, $W\times_XY$ can be identified canonically with a closed subscheme of $Y$ with underlying topological space $f^{-1}(W)$, and thus its complement is $f^{-1}(X\setminus W)=f^{-1}(U)$.

The key fact being used about the underlying topological space of the pullback of a closed subscheme came up in this question:

[Ideal of the pullback of a closed subscheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257850/ideal-of-the-pullback-of-a-closed-subscheme)

Comment: Dear @Keenan Kidwell, then the statement follows from $$f^{-1}(X\setminus W)\cong f^{-1}(X)\setminus f^{-1}(W)\cong Y\setminus f^{-1}(W)\cong Y\setminus (W\times_X Y)$$ I see, thank you.

Comment: So how do you prove that $f^{-1}(W)$ identifies with $W \times_X Y$? This is nontrivial, I think. And my gut feeling is that it may be false in the nonreduced case. Also remember the well-known special case that $W$ is the spectrum of a field, there you also have to do something ..

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, what do you mean? The fact that there are different scheme structures on the closed subset $f^{-1}(W)$ of $Y$ (but only one reduced one)?

Comment: No. "The closed immersion $W \times_X Y \to Y$ induces a homeomorphism onto $f^{-1}(W)$" needs a proof (if it is correct after all).

Comment: Hm, for topological spaces this is true. What is your definiton of $f^{-1}(W)$ as a scheme (if not $W\times_X Y$ by definition)?

Comment: Dear @Martin, I believe this follows from Proposition 4.20 in Goertz-Wedhorn. And I think that once you asked a question about this on MSE and I gave this reference...unless I'm not remembering correctly.

Comment: Dear @Ronald, $f^{-1}(W)$, as a scheme, is $W\times_YX$. One has to prove that the underlying topological spaces match up, because in general, the underlying topological space of a fiber product of schemes is not the fiber product in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Perhaps you can add http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257850/ideal-of-the-pullback-of-a-closed-subscheme to your answer.

Comment: Dear @KeenanKidwell, ah, I see, this is a very clear formulation of the problem.

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, but the positive answer of the question has then very much to do with $j$ being a closed immersion. If for example $X$ is terminal and $j$ is the morphism into the terminal object, the scheme-theoretic pullback $W\times Y$ has as its underlying topological space not the product of the topological spaces of $W$ and $Y$, i.e. $|W\times Y|\not\cong |W|\times|Y|$, right?

Comment: Yes. In general, the fiber of the continuous map $|X \times_S Y| \to |X| \times_{|Y|} |Z|$  at $(x,y,s)$ identifies with $\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa(x) \otimes_{\kappa(s)} \kappa(y))$.

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, thank you very much. Do you perhaps know if the statement of the question remains true when ''closed immersion'' is replaced by ''open immersion'' and the reduced closed subscheme structures on $X\setminus W$ and $Y\setminus (W\times_X Y)$ are taken respectively?

Comment: Dear @Ronald, I would guess that this is false just because the base change of a reduced scheme need no longer be reduced (e.g. over a field). So maybe you would want to take the reduced induced structure on $Y\times_X(X/W)$ and then ask the question. But I don't know the answer in this case.